# Sort keys in dictionary by value in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/in-python-how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary) as well as many others, but haven't quite found the answer to my question nor can I figure it out.

I have a dictionary of lists.  For example it looks like:

```
Dict = {'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[9,8,7,6], 'c':[8,5,3,2]}
```

I want to return a list of the keys sorted (descending/reverse) based on a specific item in the lists.  For example, I want to sort a,b,c based on the 4th item in each list.

This should return the list `sorted_keys = ['b','a','c']` which were sorted by values `[6,4,2]`.

Make sense?  Please help...thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Supply a `key` function, a `lambda` is easiest, and sort reversed:

```
sorted(Dict.keys(), key=lambda k: Dict[k][3], reverse=True)
```

The key function tells `sorted` what to sort *by*; the 4th item in the value for the given key.

Demo:

```
>>> sorted(Dict.keys(), key=lambda k: Dict[k][3], reverse=True)
['b', 'a', 'c']
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters +1 nice solution, you don't need `.keys()`