# Sort and return dict by specific list value

Tags: sorting, dictionary, python-3.6

I found this: [Sort keys in dictionary by value in a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152634/sort-keys-in-dictionary-by-value-in-a-list-in-python)

and it is almost what I want.  I want to sort exactly as is defined in the above post, i.e., by a specific item in the value list, but I want to return the entire original dictionary sorted by the specified list entry, not a list of the keys.

My last try has failed:

```
details = {'India': ['New Dehli', 'A'],
           'America': ['Washington DC', 'B'],
           'Japan': ['Tokyo', 'C']
           }

print('Country-Capital List...')
print(details)
print()
temp1 = sorted(details.items(), key=lambda value: details[value][1])
print(temp1)
```

The error:

```
{'India': ['New Dehli', 'A'], 'America': ['Washington DC', 'B'], 'Japan': ['Tokyo', 'C']}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 11, in <module>

    temp1 = sorted(details.items(), key=lambda value: details[value][1])
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    temp1 = sorted(details.items(), key=lambda value: details[value][1])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the `(key, value)` pair from the `dict.items()` sequence as a key. Because `value` is a list, this fails, as keys must be hashable and lists are not.

Just use the value directly:

```
temp1 = sorted(details.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][1])
```

I renamed the `lambda` argument to `item` to make it clearer what is being passed in. `item[1]` is the value from the `(key, value)` pair, and `item[1][1]` is the second entry in each list.

Demo:

```
>>> details = {'India': ['New Dehli', 'A'],
...            'America': ['Washington DC', 'B'],
...            'Japan': ['Tokyo', 'C']
...            }
>>> sorted(details.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][1])
[('India', ['New Dehli', 'A']), ('America', ['Washington DC', 'B']), ('Japan', ['Tokyo', 'C'])]
```